# play framework 2.5 starts from which file

Tags: scala, playframework, akka

I hava an akka actor. i want to start this actor at the start-up of application once in the life cycle of system.

currently i have used it at renderLoginPage Controller :

```
def loginPage: Action[AnyContent] = Action.async {
implicit request =>
  scheduler.sendReminder(kSessionService,userService)
  Logger.debug("Redirecting renderHomePage")
}
```

Following is my code of Scheduler for actor :

```
    class Scheduler{
  val system = ActorSystem("system")
  def sendReminder(kSessionService: KSessionService, userService: UserService):Unit = {
    val reminder = system.actorOf(ReminderActor.props(kSessionService,userService), "reminder-actor")
    reminder ! ReminderActor.Tick
  }

}
```

Now Problem occurring with me is : when i am logging out from the application it again renders login page and try to create the actor with same name . So i am getting an exception :

> [InvalidActorNameException: actor name [reminder-actor] is not unique!]

Where i should write the code for initiating the scheduler.

Comment: Do you want to create an actor per request? One way would be to use AkkaGuiceSupport Module. On the other hand you could use a BalancingPool and tell him how many Actors should be created. On the other hand you could leave out the naming just call system.actorOf(ReminderActor.props(kSessionService,userService))

Answer (score 1):

You could do it without specifying a actor name:

```
system.actorOf(ReminderActor.props(kSessionService,userService))
```

But depending on how you implemented your actor you could have a single actor injected in your Action and send the data with the Tick message.

```
reminder ! ReminderActor.Tick(kSessionService,userService)
```

Check eager bindings: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaDependencyInjection#Eager-bindings

I think you can do something like:

```
class Module(system: ActorSystem) extends AbstractModule {
  def configure() = {
     //Set your binding here
  }
}
```